# R - Convert Event Log (Asynchronous Log) to Time Series (Synchronous Log)

Tags: r, asynchronous, time-series

Curious if y'all have a more efficient or elegant way to convert an events log into a time series.

And not to be so tidyverse centric, but curious if you might have a nice tidyverse method mind? I was trying to take advantage of dplyr::mutate's lag function for carrying forward observations when value is NA, but I could not seem to get lag to repeat.

Here's a simple example

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
events <- tibble(
  t = runif(10, 0, 100) %>% sort(),
  value = runif(10, 0, 1)
)

events
# A tibble: 10 x 2
           t     value
       <dbl>     <dbl>
 1  6.178627 0.2059746
 2 20.168193 0.1765568
 3 26.550866 0.6870228
 4 37.212390 0.3841037
 5 57.285336 0.7698414
 6 62.911404 0.4976992
 7 66.079779 0.7176185
 8 89.838968 0.9919061
 9 90.820779 0.3800352
10 94.467527 0.7774452
```

Here's one super hacky way to do this. 
Events to time series:

```
accordian <- function(events_data, freq = 1){
  t_seq = seq(
    from = min(events_data$t)-freq %>% round(0), 
    to = max(events_data$t) + freq, 
    by = freq)
  timeseries = tibble(
    t = t_seq,
    value = NA
  )
  timeseries = bind_rows(
    events_data,
    timeseries
  ) %>%
    arrange(t) 
  for (i in 2:length(timeseries$value)){
    if (is.na(timeseries$value[i])){ timeseries$value[i] = timeseries$value[i-1] }
  }
  timeseries = timeseries %>%
    filter(t %in% t_seq)

  return(timeseries)
}

accordian(events)
# A tibble: 102 x 3
           t     value       type
       <dbl>     <dbl>      <chr>
 1  6.178627 0.2059746 events log
 2 20.168193 0.1765568 events log
 3 26.550866 0.6870228 events log
 4 37.212390 0.3841037 events log
 5 57.285336 0.7698414 events log
 6 62.911404 0.4976992 events log
 7 66.079779 0.7176185 events log
 8 89.838968 0.9919061 events log
 9 90.820779 0.3800352 events log
10 94.467527 0.7774452 events log
# ... with 92 more rows
```

And to make clear the distinction between the events log and time-series based on the events log:

```
library(ggplot2)
bind_rows(
  events %>%
    mutate(type = "events log"),
  accordian(events) %>%
    mutate(type = "time series"),
) %>%
ggplot(
  aes(x = t, y = value, color = type)
) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

I'd love to get your advice!

Comment: I am facing the same problem at the moment. Did you end up finding a nice way to do this? I tried using the code in your question on my asynchronous event log but there were some problems, probably due to the fact that my time variable is in DateTime format.

Comment: Hmm, maybe we should make a package together?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with a DateTime var too, but didn't want to add an extra layer to the simple example. I'll post my -- still not great -- solution in a week or so.

Comment: I don't know if I have the know-how to make a package like that, but we could try. I've made a asynchronous-to-synchronous function in base R that seems to work, maybe we could translate that to a tidyverse solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but based on your comment I'd like to show you my base-R approach. Perhaps we can translate it into a tidyverse solution:

```
async_to_sync <- function(async_df) {
  # Creates a synchronous (multivariate) time series from an asynchronous event log.
  # It is assumed the asynchronous log contains no missing values.

  # creates simple time sequence, could be modified to have a different freuency
  time_sequence <- seq(min(async_df$time), max(async_df$time), by = 1)

  # constructing a new empty dataframe:
  sync_df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(async_df), nrow = length(time_sequence)))
  colnames(sync_df) <- colnames(async_df)
  sync_df$time <- time_sequence

  # Fill in already known values in the synchronous time series:
  for(i in 1:nrow(async_df)) {
    time_value <- async_df$time[i]
    sync_df[which(sync_df$time == time_value, arr.ind = TRUE), ] <- async_df[i, ] 
  }

  # Filling in the blanks:
  for(i in 1:nrow(sync_df)) {
    if(sync_df[i, ] %>% is.na %>% any) {
      sync_df[i, ] <- sync_df[i - 1, ]
    }
  }

  return(sync_df)
}
```

Running this on an example:

```
> set.seed(1234)
> async_df <- data.frame(time = c(2, 6, 7, 14), x1 = LETTERS[1:4], x2 = 1:4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> async_df
  time x1 x2
1    2  A  1
2    6  B  2
3    7  C  3
4   14  D  4
> async_to_sync(async_df = async_df)
   time x1 x2
1     2  A  1
2     2  A  1
3     2  A  1
4     2  A  1
5     6  B  2
6     7  C  3
7     7  C  3
8     7  C  3
9     7  C  3
10    7  C  3
11    7  C  3
12    7  C  3
13   14  D  4
```